# Upload a empty folder with js or jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, forms, input

hello there I am building a folder upload system with js and PHP
but I got an issue I'm not able to upload a folder that not contains any files

I use

```
    <input type="file" id="picker" name="files" webkitdirectory multiple>
```

and for getting the file i use

```
    $('input[type="file"]').on("change", function (e) {
        let files = $(this).get(0).files;
        console.log(files);
    });
```

if a folder contains any file so I can easily access the folder using

```
files[i].webkitRelativePath
```

what is the problem
I'm just getting files that contain webkitRelativePath not getting the folders directly
so I'm not able to get any empty subfolders with this approach

can anyone tell me how to access folders directly without webkitRelativePath or anything else so I can handle empty subfolders

Comment: I suspect that there is no way to "upload" an empty folder. I would suggest that if a folder is empty, no files, that you'd simply be asking PHP to create a folder. So maybe if the count of files is 0, simple have PHP make the folder versus trying to upload an empty folder.

Comment: There's [Filesystem Access API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_System_Access_API), but it's not widely supported, as well as [webkitRelativePath](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/webkitRelativePath) isn't (the MDN example crashed FF).

Comment: how to access the name of that empty folder dear @ Twisty